# Vue.js props not showing actual message value, What have I done and how can I solve it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning vue.js and for my practice purpuse I am making an chatting app. in my chatlog component I used props. when I print those property in console it's ok and print all the object in console but in templete they all are vanished. My code is bellow.
Thanks in advance.

Chatlog

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-log">
        <button @click="showOnConsole">Show on console</button>
        <p>{{ messages}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
     props: ['messages'],
     methods: {
        showOnConsole()
        {
            console.log(messages);
        }
     }

    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        messages: []
    },
    created: function() {
        axios.get('/Chat/public/messages')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.messages = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include your app HTML. That is where you pass the props to the component.

Comment: Actually my backend is laravel 5.4 and there is chat.blade.php. Did you mean it? I passed from here

<chat-log :messages="messages"></chat-log>
                    <chat-composer v-on:sendmessage="messageAdd"></chat-composer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your `created` method, so you bind your own `this`:

```
created: function() {
    axios.get('/Chat/public/messages')
        .then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Or without using an arrow function:

```
created: function() {
    var that = this

    axios.get('/Chat/public/messages')
        .then(function (response) {
            that.messages = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```